# Find number of possible path in NxM rectangular grid which visit some specific blocks?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

There is one robot at (1,1) in nxm rectangular room. Robot can go down and right only. Now there are s specific fruits on some specific blocks(i,j).
Depending on health of his owner, he need to get f ( 0<=f<= s ) fruits and take them to owner which is at (n,m).

For given f , how many possible path exist ?

It is an programming interview question.

I understand,  No of possible path from 1,1 to n,m is (n+m C n).
But how to approach with specific blocks ?

Comment: it's hard to give full fledged advice without spoiling it all - but if you (the robot) are at `(n,m)` you must have brought at least `f` fruits with you - and you came there either from the left or from the top - depending if there is a fruit at one of those positions the number *of fruits to have* will drop at those locations - you see: the only thing different from the problem without the *fruits* is that you have to remember the number of ways indexed by the fruits to gather and drop at (1,1) all those who still need fruits - the rest is your 101 DP algorithm ... I hope this helps you a bit

Comment: Think about a DP state that captures all the necessary information

Comment: Another way to think about this: if you need to stop by the grocery store before you go home, then how many paths are there that visit the grocery store and then go home? For each path that takes you to the grocery store, you can take any path home after you're done at the grocery store. What basic mathematical operation can express this?

Comment: It doesn't seem so linear to me. For any `f < s`, there are `s choose f` possible combinations of fruit to collect, each combination potentially yielding a different number of paths. Consider the example of a 2x3 grid with `s = {(1,1),(2,2),(2,3)}; f = 2`. If we choose (1,1) and (2,2), there are 2 paths; but if we choose (1,1) and (2,3), there are 3 paths.